# laravel deleting user (cant get the id of the user)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I'm having an issue deleting a user.
I cannot get the id of the user I wish to delete.
Any help is appreciated.

view

```
 <form method="post" action="/staff/{{$user->id}}">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
 {{csrf_field()}}
 <button style="padding: 0" type="submit" class="btn btn-link margin-left-40"
 onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete {{ucfirst($user->name)}}?');">
 <i class="icmn-bin"></i> Delete</button>
 </form>
```

controller

```
   public function destroy(User $user)
{

    $thisuser = User::find($user->id);
    $thisuser->delete();

    return redirect('/staff');
}
```

route

```
Route::resource('/staff', 'User\UserController');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $thisuser = User::find($id);
    $thisuser->delete();

    return redirect('/staff');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('staff.destroy',$user->id)}}">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
{{csrf_field()}}
<button style="padding: 0" type="submit" class="btn btn-link margin-left-40"
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete 
 {{ucfirst($user->name)}}?');">
 <i class="icmn-bin"></i> Delete</button>
</form>
```

//your route

```
Route::get('/staff/{id}/delete', 'User\UserController@destroy')->name('staff.destroy');
```

//method

```
   public function destroy($id)
 {

   $thisuser = User::find($id);
   $thisuser->delete();

   return redirect('/staff');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //Soft delete
    $thisuser = User::destroy($id);

    //OR

    //Permanent Delete 
    $thisuser = User::where('id',$id)->delete();


    return redirect('/staff');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kuldeep Mishra's solution, make sure your form is properly bound to the user you intend to delete.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
 <form method="post" action="/staff/{{$user->id}}">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
 {{csrf_field()}} 
 <button style="padding: 0" type="submit" class="btn btn-link margin-left- 
 40" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete   
 {{ucfirst($user->name)}}?');">
 <i class="icmn-bin"></i> Delete</button>
 </form>
```

**route**

```
Route::delete('/staff/{id}', 'UserController@destroy');
```

**function**

```
public function destroy($id)
{

     $thisuser = User::find($id);
     $thisuser->delete();

     return redirect('/staff');
}
```